# How do I test my coupon at simulator passbook? - IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, passbook

I have created an coupon.pkpass, how do I test my coupon at simulator passbook? I want to know that my coupon is created successful or not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through these Passbook tutorials from Raywenderlich, may help you

Will also explain you how you can make use of it in real life time.

[Beginning Passbook in iOS 6: Part 1/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20734/beginning-passbook-part-1)

[Beginning Passbook in iOS 6: Part 2/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20785/beginning-passbook-in-ios-6-part-22)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to drag the .pkpass bundle from finder into the Simulator.

To get a .pkpass bundle to display on the Simulator via Safari, you will need to serve it via a web server with a MIME type of `application/vnd.apple.pkpass`.

Since OSX ships with Apache built in you can drop the .pkpass file in your ~/Sites folder and access it via Safari on the simulator at `http://localhost/~yourUsername/your.pkpass`

[This site](http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/02/start-apache-web-server-mac-os-x/) gives a step by step guide for how to get Apache up and running with Mountain Lion.

To add the .pkpass MIME type you'll need to add the following line to /etc/apache2/mime.types

```
application/vnd.apple.pkpass    .pkpass
```